# Rig affecting other meshes that I don't want to affect

Tags: rigging

I'm a beginner at rigging. And I have no idea what to do here.
So I rigged my model, and when I move the thumbs, it affects part of the head as well.

Screenshot:[image: The model]

[image: Moving the thumb affects the glasses]

[image: The rig]

Completely stuck here. Anyone got any tips?

Comment: Have you checked your object's weight painting by selecting your object and changing from whatever mode you're in (object, edit, pose, etc) to weight paint mode, selecting the problematic bone, and seeing if it has influence over the head part of your mesh?

Comment: yeah, no luck, it appears to be normal

Comment: Could you try uploading your blend file so others can help determine what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here my Andy robot has a headache. His head is being posed by his hand.
[image: Andy has a headache]

So we'll switch the mesh to edit mode, deselect everything, and choose the hand.r vertex group. That's the bone causing Andy's problem.
[image: Into edit mode]

Then we'll click the "select" button
[image: Click select]

We see Andy's hand is selected, but so is a portion of the head!
[image: The group selected]

We'll use <kbd>c</kbd> and the <kbd>shift</kbd> to deselect all the valid hand parts.
[image: Deselect that which is good]

Then we'll click the "Remove" button to remove the selected head verts from the hand.r group
[image: click the "Remove" button]

Now Andy's headache is gone!
[image: Fini]

Note: Andy is a model from imported from Poser.

Comment: Hello; I have tried doing this but it selects the hand only, not the head. I've uploaded the blend file above.

Comment: So in your case select the object Char_Torture_Glasses, go into edit mode as described and select bone.015 group and click Remove

Comment: ive tried doing it but it still doesn't work

Comment: You've got some really messy vertex groups. Since you have individual objects do this:

Comment: For each object:
 - remove all the vertex groups that don't belong to a bone in your armature.
 - remove all the vertex groups for bones that don't control this object

Comment: nvm: it worked, guess i was just being an idiot

had to remove bone.014 and 0.15

Answer (score 0):

My other answer is more general and doesn't exactly address your specific problem. It looks like you need to watch a few videos on rig design and weight painting, but in the interest of helping you fix your current character let me offer you the following:

Here we have the object "Char_Torture_Head" selected in object mode. Notice there are many, many vertex groups we don't need, and the armature bones for the head, neck and shoulders are named "Bone", "Bone.003", "Bone.008", and "Bone.010"
[image: Head, before]

Now I've renamed the armature bones "Char_Torture_Head", "Char_Torture_Neck", "Char_Torture_Shoulder.L", "Char_Torture_Shoulder.R". Blender automatically renamed the appropriate vertex groups. I then deleted all the vertex groups but those 4 from the head as shown below. Also, many cool features require left and right bones to have the suffix .L and .R to work correctly.
[image: Head, after]

The glasses have the same problem, extraneous vertex groups.
[image: Glasses before]

The bones for the glasses already have meaningful names so just delete the extra groups.
[image: Glasses after]