# Problem with rigging shoes on a character

Tags: rigging

I have a problem with rigging shoes on a character. Shoes are deforming as I try to move the leg. I don't know if it's a problem with armature or weight painting.

Thank you very much.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe remove these vertices from all groups (you can access this function in the dropdown menu on the right of the Vertex Groups list) then reassign in Weight Paint mode?

Comment: See my answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/234746/33589